# How to store an array of String with Core Data in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to understand which is the good way (and suggested by Apple) for storing an array of String ([String]) using the framework Core Data with SwiftUI.

I haven't found any clear documentation about.

For what I saw, I should create an attribute of type Transformable and then set the "Custom Class" to [String]

[image]

[image]

But then I start to see some warnings at build time:

> warning: Misconfigured Property: Wine.pairings is using a nil or insecure value transformer. Please switch to NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName or a custom NSValueTransformer subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer

So, I'm wondering that maybe this is not the good approach.

Comment: My recommendation is to forget heavy `NSCoding` and en-/decode the string to/from JSON with `Codable` and map it with a computed property.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about a way like this, but I would like to use the native API offered by Core Data

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: screenshot of core data model]

If you put NSSecureUnarchiveFromData into the Transformer field (the one above custom class in your data model) the warning goes away

Comment: ah perfect, I see that it works, in fact it has generated in the properties file the following attribute `public var pairings: [String]? { get set }`